# Custom search on Knowledge Articles. Need pros and cons

Tags: knowledge

What are the pros and cons on implementation of our own search (using either soql or sosl) on knowledge articles instead of using standard knowledge components for search and display. Is it really possible to perform soql on knowledge articles and customize where condition and use multiple data categories....

Answer (score 2):

I would say the main disadvantages would be that search is tough. If you just want to see if it contains a word or phrase then that probably wouldn't be too hard - if you want to go beyond that it can get a lot tougher very quickly.

The other issue may be that depending on how many articles you have you may start to run in to Salesforce governor limitations, especially if someone does a basic search.

I'm not really sure how sophisticated the default search is, so I would really only consider doing it if there is important functionality that you need that they don't provide.

Comment: Some powerful standard features you'd be missing out on with custom article search would also be:

Stemming: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=knowledge_article_search_stemming.htm&language=en_US

Knowledge Synonyms: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_how_synonyms_work.htm&language=en_US